# MySQL SELECT query with many joins takes too long

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

I have a select query in mysql which returns almost *a million* records. That takes almost *2 and half minutes* 151 seconds to be exact. How can I improve the performance that it brings the data quickly.

```
SELECT 
      s.status, s.timestamp, s.comment, s.duration, s.enter enterTimestamp, 
      r.name room, r.number roomNumber, r.size roomSize, r.room_type otherRoomType, 
      u.id userId, u.fullname cleaner, 
      c.name customer, 
      a.name area, a.type areaType, 
      i.name instruction, 
      p.plantype planType, 
      rt.name roomType, 
      f.name floor, 
      b.name building, 
      cori.time estimatedDuration, 
      m.fullname manager 
FROM coris s 
      LEFT JOIN room r ON s.room_id = r.id 
      LEFT JOIN user u ON s.user_id = u.id 
      LEFT JOIN area a ON s.area_id = a.id 
      LEFT JOIN instruction i ON s.instruction_id = i.id 
      LEFT JOIN plan p ON a.id = p.area_id 
      LEFT JOIN roomtype rt ON r.roomtype_id = rt.id 
      LEFT JOIN customer c ON r.customer_id = c.id 
      LEFT JOIN floor f ON r.floor_id = f.id 
      LEFT JOIN building b ON f.building_id = b.id 
      LEFT JOIN cori ON s.cori_id = cori.id 
      LEFT JOIN user m ON u.manager_id = m.id 
WHERE 
     s.timestamp >  '2019-06-03 00:00:00.0' AND s.timestamp < '2020-06-03 23:59:59.999' 
ORDER BY s.timestamp ASC
```

I have indexing on `timestamp` in `coris s` table also. I have tried creating a view of this query but no improvment. Any help? How can I get the data quickly so I don't have to wait for so long.

This is what I got from `EXPLAIN {query}`
[image]

Comment: 'returns almost a million records' - how many records in coris?

Comment: 1.4 million and it increases on daily basis

Comment: `EXPLAIN {query}` to make sure its being used. What mysql server version/hardware resource/configuration?

Comment: I didn't get it. what do you mean by this EXPLAIN {query}?

Comment: mysql server version is 5.6

Comment: the sql statement `EXPLAIN {query}` with the query substituted will show you how it is executing the query, including which indexes are used. What server my.cnf files you do you have? Can you include this information in the question?

Comment: I have added `EXPLAIN {query}` result in question.